# Xcode 9.2 folders always open?

Tags: xcode, directory

In Xcode 9.2 I am finding that my project folders are always open on launch (disclosure triangles down.) The somewhat defeats the purpose of project folders as I have one project with a huge number of folders.  Any way to restrain this irritating behavior?

Comment: It takes one click to close them all, so what's the big deal?

Comment: True if you want to close all of them. I never do. I want the first level open if that is the last layout I chose. Just a user-friendly step Apple misses.  The finder is the same. Every time I open the Applications folder I want it to show versions, but does it?  No! Nor can macOS remember that I want certain things, like size. The Finder area has no persistence. However I leave things is never remembered.

Comment: Try updating to Xcode 10, it might do this better. If not, file an enhancement request with Apple. This is not really a Stack Overflow question.